# remove if exists in fish

Tags: bash, fish

I have started using `fish` and I understand that there are couple of major differences between `fish` and regular bash (I have used mac terminal).

Some of my alias didn't work which I was able to fix. However, I am not able to fix following. Basically, I want to remove all files which match the given extensions.

```
alias texclr=rm -v *.aux *.log *.out *.spl *.bbl *.synctex.gz *.blg *.lof *.lot *.tdo *.toc *.idx *.nav *.snm *.a* *.g* *.l* *.ist *.run.xml *-blx.* *.fff *.bcf
```

However, it doesn't appear to work and produces an errors at first occurrence of non-matching file.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way I can delete files if exists (preferably one liner)?
2. Is it rather conceptually wrong?

Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: Note that, as written, your alias will expand the globs when it is defined. You should quote the part after the "=".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fish, since version 2.3.0, will print an error and not execute the command for unmatching globs for every command except `for`, `set` and `count`.

That means you should assign the matching files to a variable with

```
set -l files *.aux *.log # and so on
```

Because this requires a second command, it should be a full function instead of an alias (which in fish is just syntactic sugar for functions anyway):

```
function texclr
    set -l files *.aux *.log *.out *.spl *.bbl *.synctex.gz *.blg *.lof *.lot *.tdo *.toc *.idx *.nav *.snm *.a* *.g* *.l* *.ist *.run.xml *-blx.* *.fff *.bcf
    rm -v $files
end
```

If you want to not execute the `rm` at all if there are no matching files (to avoid ugly error messages), you can use `set -q files[1]; and rm -v $files`.

Comment: I was thinking in same direction.